# Keys of hash as arrays and keys values into arrays after match

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I have given shown file as input to script and created an hash. I want to make keys as arrays and the corresponding key values into that array after the match.

I have created hash, but finding issues to create keys as arrays and its values into the corresponding array. Any help is highly appreciated.

Expected output is as below

```perl
@school = (STRING_x, STRING_y, STRING_z,STRING_k)
@University = (STRING_a, STRING_b, STRING_c)s
@College = (STRING_d, STRING_e, STRING_f)
```

Input file

```
begin_
No,59,Type:,School,Authors:,,,,
Local,config
0,0,0,STRING_x,256
1,0,1,STRING_y,256
2,0,2,STRING_z,256
3,0,3,STRING_k,256
end,,,,,

begin_
No,99,Type:,University,Authors:,,,
Local,config
0,0,0,STRING_a,64
0,0,0,STRING_b,64
0,0,0,STRING_c,64
end,,,,,

begin_
No,234,Type:,College,Authors:,,,
Local,config
0,0,0,STRING_d,32
0,0,0,STRING_e,32
0,0,0,STRING_f,32
end,,,,,
```

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use feature qw(say);

my $csv= "./file.txt";  

die "cannot open csv\n" if (!open(CSV, "<$csv" ));

my %storage;
my $compiler;
my $macro;

my @bil = qw(
  STRING_a STRING_b STRING_c STRING_d STRING_e
  STRING_f STRING_x STRING_y STRING_z STRING_k
);

while (<CSV>){
    chomp(my $line =$_);
    next if ($line !~ /^No|^\d+/ );
    $compiler = $1 if ($line =~ /No,\d+,Type:,(\w+)/);

    if ($line =~ /\d+,\d+,\d+,(\w+),/){
        $macro=$1;
        push @{$storage{$compiler}},$1;
    }
}

close CSV;
print Dumper \%storage;

for my $bil(@bil) {
    while (my ($k,$v) =each%storage ){
        print "Line-----$bil,,,, $v\n";
        if ($bil =~$v){
            #Need help (I want to store the $v into an array having the name $k)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps. It processes the file in two stages.

Stage 1 parses the input data, extracting the information that is useful to us and stores it in a hash. The keys of the hash are array names and the values in  the hash are array references containing the elements of the array.

Stage 2 walks the has we built in stage 1 and turns it into the required output.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

# Where we're going to store the useful bits of the
# data during the parsing stage
my %data;
# Where we store the name of the current hash key.
my $key;

# Stage 1: Parsing
while (<>) {
  # This looks for the array name record, extracts the
  # string from between "Type" and "Authors" and stores that
  # string as $key
  if (/Type:,(\w+),Authors:/) {
    $key = $1;
  }

  # This looks for "STRING" record, extracts that from the input
  # line and pushes that onto the end of the current array reference
  if (/(STRING[^,]+)/) {
    push @{$data{$key}}, $1;
  }
}

# Stage 2: Output
# For each key in the data hash...
for (keys %data) {
  # ... extract the data we want and print it
  say '@', "$_ = (", join(', ', @{$data{$_}}), ')';
}
```

**Update:** Ok, let's look at the final loop in a bit more detail.

We have a hash, called `%data` that contains information that we have parsed from the input file. The keys are things like "School" and "College" and the values are an array reference.

We start by looping over the keys of that hash. We could just print those keys.

```
foreach (keys %data) {
  say $_;
}
```

Note that each time we go round this loop, the variable `$_` contains one of the keys from the hash. Because hashes are sorted randomly, we get those keys back in a random order each time.

You want the key name to be preceded by an "@". That's simple enough to do:

```
foreach (keys %data) {
  say '@', $_;
}
```

It might be tempting to put that into a double-quoted string (`"@$_"`) but Perl would then interpret the "@" as the start of an array variable (which it isn't here). So the simplest fix is to split the string into two parts.

We then want the string to have "=(STUFF)" - so let's add that.

```
foreach (keys %data) {
  say '@', "$_ = (STUFF)";
}
```

Of course, "STUFF" is a bit more complicated. We can start by printing the value from the hash:

```
foreach (keys %data) {
  say '@', "$_ = ($data{$_})";
}
```

But that doesn't give us what we want:

```
@College = (ARRAY(0x55c35f9c8fd0))
@University = (ARRAY(0x55c35f9c8e68))
@School = (ARRAY(0x55c35f9d23e8))
```

That's because what we have is an array *reference*. So we need to dereference it.

```
for (keys %data) {
  say '@', "$_ = (@{$data{$_}})";
}
```

That gets us closer:

```
@University = (STRING_a STRING_b STRING_c)
@School = (STRING_x STRING_y STRING_z STRING_k)
@College = (STRING_d STRING_e STRING_f)
```

But you asked for commas between the elements in the list. We can do that using `join()`, but we need to split apart the bits of the output string - as you can't call functions inside a string. It might be easier to understand if we put each part of the output string on a separate line:

```
for (keys %data) {
  say '@',
      "$_ = (",
      join(', ', @{$data{$_}}),
      ')';
}
```

We're printing four sections here:

1. The initial "@"
2. The key name (in `$_`) along with the next, fixed parts of the string
3. A string we generate from calling `join()` passing it ", " and our dereferenced array
4. A closing ")" for the end of our list

Putting these all together, gives us this output:

```
@College = (STRING_d, STRING_e, STRING_f)
@School = (STRING_x, STRING_y, STRING_z, STRING_k)
@University = (STRING_a, STRING_b, STRING_c)
```

One thing I forgot to mention is that I got rid of your code that hardcoded the input file name and opened the file. It's simpler and more flexible to just read the data from the command line. That's what

```
while (<>) {
  ...
}
```

does. It just reads data from filenames that are passed on the command line and puts each line in turn into `$_`.

I hope that makes things clearer.

Comment: Many thanks for your help and the comments describing the script!!. Last line looks a bit complex to understand how the array is created. I could understand that the elements are joined using join function, but couldn't get the rest. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Below is a restructured version of your code.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use feature qw(say);

my $csv= "./file.txt";

open(CSV, "<", $csv )
    or die "cannot open csv\n";

my %storage;
my $compiler;

my %bil = map { $_ => 1}
          qw(
            STRING_a
            STRING_b
            STRING_c
            STRING_d
            STRING_e
            STRING_f
            STRING_x
            STRING_y
            STRING_z
            STRING_k
        );

while (<CSV>){
    chomp(my $line = $_);

    next
        if $line !~ /^No|^\d+/ ;

    $compiler = $1
        if ($line =~ /No,\d+,Type:,(\w+)/);

    if ($line =~ /\d+,\d+,\d+,(\w+),/){
        my $macro = $1;
        push @{ $storage{$compiler} }, $1;
    }
}

close CSV;
# print Dumper \%storage;

my @school     = grep { $bil{$_} } @{ $storage{School}     } ;
my @University = grep { $bil{$_} } @{ $storage{University} } ;
my @College    = grep { $bil{$_} } @{ $storage{College}    } ;

say "school     [@school]";
say "University [@University]";
say "College    [@College]";
```

running gives this output

```
school     [STRING_x STRING_y STRING_z STRING_k]
University [STRING_a STRING_b STRING_c]
College    [STRING_d STRING_e STRING_f]
```

If the full list of `compilers`, (i.e. School, University, College) is only available in  `file.txt`, you can modify the code as follows to get it to create a `results` hash that stores the data for each of the `compilers`

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use feature qw(say);

my $csv= "./file.txt";

open(CSV, "<", $csv )
    or die "cannot open csv\n";

my %storage;
my $compiler;
my @compilers;

my %bil = map { $_ => 1}
          qw(
            STRING_a
            STRING_b
            STRING_c
            STRING_d
            STRING_e
            STRING_f
            STRING_x
            STRING_y
            STRING_z
            STRING_k
        );

while (<CSV>){
    chomp(my $line = $_);

    next
        if $line !~ /^No|^\d+/ ;

    if ($line =~ /No,\d+,Type:,(\w+)/) {
        $compiler = $1 ;
        push @compilers, $compiler;
    }

    if ($line =~ /\d+,\d+,\d+,(\w+),/){
        my $macro = $1;
        push @{ $storage{$compiler} }, $1;
    }
}

close CSV;

my %results ;

for my $comp (@compilers)
{
    @{ $results{$comp} } = grep { $bil{$_} } @{ $storage{$comp} } ;
}

say Dumper \%results;
```

output is

```
$VAR1 = {
          'University' => [
                            'STRING_a',
                            'STRING_b',
                            'STRING_c'
                          ],
          'School' => [
                        'STRING_x',
                        'STRING_y',
                        'STRING_z',
                        'STRING_k'
                      ],
          'College' => [
                         'STRING_d',
                         'STRING_e',
                         'STRING_f'
                       ]
        };
```